# I have a line graph and the line is too thick, which option can I choose to make it thinner?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to make the line thinner for improved viewing. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

Just right click on the line itself in the graph and you'll see menu items to adjust the width (along with color, point size, point style, and a bunch of other factors). Also, if you click a graph, you'll see options in the ribbon (see below) which you can also use to format the design of the graph.

[image]

Comment: More specifically: Chart Tools -> Format -> Shape outline -> Weight